# Find all Pairs definition

Tags: isabelle

I want to make a definition in Isabelle which returns all the pairs of a map function.
I have the following definition in Z

```
\begin{schema}[X, Y, Z]
allPairs: (X \pfun (Y \rel Z)) \fun (Y \rel Z)
where
\<forall f: (X \<pfun (Y \rel Z)) @ 
allPairs f == \<bigcup{x:X | x \in \dom f @ fx}
\end{schema}
```

Therefore I want to make a definition which takes an element of type
`(X \<rightharpoonup> ((Y * Z) set)))` or `(X \<rightharpoonup> (Y \<rightharpoonup> Z))` in isabelle and return `((Y * Z) set)` for both.

I have the following so far

```
definition allPairs ::
"('X \<rightharpoonup ('Y * 'Z) set) => ('Y * 'Z) set"
where
"allPairs f == ⋃{yz. yz ∈ ran f}"
```